# Inline elements with <br /> behaves strangely inside a inline-block

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

- Why the following code does not render the same on Chrome and Firefox (both on Mac)?
- How can I make both render the same?

Chrome
[image]

Firefox
[image]

```html
<p style="display:inline-block">some <span>te<br/>xt</span></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like browsers render the whitespace differently, adding `white-space:pre;` helps.

> **`white-space:pre`** Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

```html
<p style="display:inline-block;white-space:pre;">some <span>te<br/>xt</span></p>
```